# Java book for image editing such as brightness/contrast etc (newbie friendly)

Tags: java, user-interface, image-processing

Is there any book or very informative tutorial site which can help newbies learn how to alter pixels with a loaded image in the java GUI? I want to learn how exactly I would be able to do things such as changing the brightness and contrast of an image, invert it, smooth it and also learn how to do histograms.

So far I only know how to use Image/ImageIO/Mediatracker/BufferedImage to load and track the image but I can't find anything in particular on how to do the algorithms and editing of images for the things mentioned above. I've found random sites at most whcih give some code but no explanation on how it was done in relation to pixels etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, ImageIO, BufferedImage etc. is the way to go.  You can directly read and write pixels to manipulate, or you can get a raster.  Look for **Java game programming** books with chapters like "Advanced Graphics".  I don't know which current editions are good, but they are plentiful and I read a few good ones about 8 years ago.

Comment: Any books you recommend?

Comment: I don't have any specific current title to recommend.